# Google Maps Infowindow Position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have a problem with this code, when i click on a marker I want the infowindow to open up at that marker's position.

When i click on every marker they all open up on the same position.

code:

```
App.map = function (data, cb) {
  App.getData(App.config.LFMurl(), function (data) {
    App.processData(data, function(arr){      
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions)

  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude)

      var marker

      $.each(arr, function (index, item) {            
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.long),
          map: map,              
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP        
        })
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){                            
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({                
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.long),                                
            content: item.title
          })
          infowindow.open(map, this)
          console.log(item.artist)              
        })
      }) 

      map.setCenter(pos)
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true)          
    })
  } else {      
    handleNoGeolocation(false) // Browser som inte stödjer geolocation
  }
})
})
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it to work...

at the bottom i did this:

```
infowindow.open(map, this)
```

changed 'this' with 'marker'